# Rider for Unreal - perforce integration with files that are not in project subdirectories

Tags: plugins, perforce, jetbrains-ide, rider, jetbrains-rider

I used Rider for Unreal for quite some time now, I got used to it so much that at the other company I work I wanted to use it as well, the only problem is that I cannot make the perforce plugin work properly.

I have no trouble connecting to the server, setting up workspace etc.

The problem is that all the source code is referenced in projects as AdditionalIncludeDirectories which for some reason this plugin has a problem with.

I cannot sync, edit, or add the files even tho I am connected properly to the p4 server via the plugin.

Is there a way to tell the plugin, that the files are not in the subdirectories of given projects, but still in the workspace view of course.

Answer (score 1):

And here is the answer, I haven't seen the directory mapping

[image]